# Where can I find a list of professional StarCraft 2 players?

Tags: starcraft-2

I'm looking for a place where I could find a list of the handles for professional SC2 players - i.e. players who play StarCraft 2 for a living and are usually ranked very high on the ladders and famous from tournaments and other events.

Any list will do, but I prefer ones that rank the players according to some sort of metric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Liquidpedia](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Players_%28All%29) lists 'current' SC2 Players.
Everyone on those lists are associated with teams that have sponsorship (i.e. get money to finance their gaming).
Bear in mind that SC2 is still relatively new and the professional scene is still developing. A lot of BW players have not yet transitioned, and not counting the beta period, only a few tournaments have been held. Out of these, the only one with a 'professional' prize pool is the ongoing TG GSL, which is giving out ~85k usd to the winner iirc.

Be sure to check the Ro64 GomTV TG GSL brackets list for more info. Not everyone there is a 'professional' SC2 player, but most of them have team sponsorship.

Cheers!

Comment: I think you want this link [on liquidpedia](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Players_%28All%29 "sorted")

Comment: Yeah, that's a better one (and is right at the gates of Portal:Players >D), no need to browse by region. Thx tz.

Comment: I updated your answer with this link.  Just happy to help.